# Button get extra white space

Tags: css

I got extra space next to the button corners as shown in the image,
the container has border-radius and overflow:hidden.
and the button has width:100% without radius.

so, what makes this behavior? and how can I avoid that?

```
.button-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.button{
   padding: 20px 30px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: flex-start;
   width: 100%;
   font-size: 0.75rem;
   font-weight: 600;
   line-height: 14px;
   color: #fff;
   gap: 10px;
   border: unset;
   background-color: #3c4365;;
   cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Unwanted behavior image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22ET3.png)

Comment: If you mean the white pixels, that is the background: #ffffff;

Comment: So how can I make the button fill these pixels?

Comment: I would actually leave the .button-container, or set it the same background-color as the button (#3c4365).

Comment: @H3AR7B3A7 nailed it below here, though. Serious clever css-thinking there!

Answer (score 1):

It's the box-shadow, try adding an inset:

```css
.button-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25), 0px 0px 8px rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.25) inset;
    border-radius: 4px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Here's an example in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/H3AR7B3A7/b17q8rhd/2/).

Comment: I tried without box-shadow and got the same. also, I tried your solution don't work. I think this is about button place because when I change container bg color this extra space in the corner takes container bg color also.

Comment: @MostafaHassan Both removing `box-shadow` and my solution work perfectly fine for me. Try hard refreshing your browser: press Ctrl + F5. Or try it in the fiddle, you'll see.